# Using a list of integers to reference the indices of another list to return a specific value from that list

Tags: python, list, loops

In my program, I'm trying to make a basic encryption program with a simple shift of letters to encrypt an input message.  A user provides input, the letters are compared to a list and returns an output of integers into a new list.  The integers from the new list reference the indices of the first list and return the corresponding strings (letters).  This will be a function that I will be able to use in future, simple, programs.

So my main problem is, I get a list containing integers but I haven't figured out a way to use those integers to reference the values of the other list (alpha) to get the new letters.  Anyone know how to do that or is it even possible?  Thank you!

Here's my code below:

```
def alpha_trans():
    #  Asks user for input to be decrypted
    word = input("Word or phrase to translate: ")
    alpha = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u",
             "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", " ", ".", "!", "?", "@", "#", "$", "%", "&"]
    encrypt = []

    #  Takes input from user and compares to list above for decrypting
    for letter in word:
        # Takes index of characters from input, then adds 2
        offset = alpha.index(letter) + 2
        # Puts integers (alpha index + 2) into the encrypt list
        encrypt.append(offset)
    # Confirm contents of new list
    print(encrypt)
# End of Function

alpha_trans()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need this:

```
encrypt.append(alpha[offset])
```

Comment: I see I was on the right track in line 13, but this did the trick!!!  Thank you so much!